# Selenium: Wait for element's width to be greater than X

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a page that does some processing and displays a progress bar.

I want to press the cancel button when the filling of the progress bar has at least 50% width.

How can I create a custom wait condition ?

```
    driver.findElement(By.id('bar')).then(function (stateEl) {
      // driver.wait(until. ?? By.xpath? 
    }).then(done);
```

Comment: Are you using protractor or webdriver.js?

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj webdriver.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use explicit `driver.wait` functionality, where you return `true` or `false` value to release or hold the driver.

http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html#wait

You can do something like:

```
  driver.wait(function() {
    return Promise.all([
      driver.findElement(progressBarWrapper).getSize(),
      driver.findElement(progressBar).getSize()
    ]).then(function(sizes) {
      return (sizes[0].width / 2) <= sizes[1].width;
    });
  }, timeout);
```

I assumed, that you have a wrapper (a box for your progress bar, its width is max width of progress bar) and the actual progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

please try below code

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(dr,10);  
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<boolean>(){  
    @Override  
    public boolean apply(WebDriver d) {  
        return d.findElement(By.id("origressid")).getAttribute("value")>50%;  
    }}).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
driver.wait(function() {
return driver.findElement(progressbar_locator).getAttribute("value")
       .then(function (value) {
          return value >=50;
        })
}, 5000);
```

Here I'm just assuming that the progress bar element will have an attribute named "value" which will change dynamically based on the progress bar percentage. In your case, you need to identify a way to know when the progress bar value gets changed.